# Quarterly data with daily frequency calculations in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

my problem is that I have some data that is quarterly but needs be recalculated daily using another daily value. Basically, I am working with quarterly financial data but I need to recalculate some of the ratios for a daily frequency using daily price data. In this case below, I am given a value for c.atq and c.csh12q quarterly and  a value for s1.prccd daily. I need to calculate the ratio for the current c.atq using the current s1.prccd. When the the c.atq changes at the end of the quarter, the process should continue with the new value.

```
 select s1.DATADATE, c.ATQ, s1.PRCCD, c.ATQ/(s1.PRCCD*c.CSH12Q) as PATQ
 from sec_dprc s1 
 left outer join co_ifndq c 
 on s1.GVKEY = c.GVKEY
 and s1.DATADATE = c.DATADATE
 where s1.GVKEY = 008068
 order by s1.DATADATE
```

this is small table of the results:

```
DATADATE            ATQ     PRCCD   PATQ
19/12/1984 00:00    NULL    28      NULL
20/12/1984 00:00    NULL    27.25   NULL
21/12/1984 00:00    NULL    27.5    NULL
24/12/1984 00:00    NULL    27.5    NULL
26/12/1984 00:00    NULL    27.5    NULL
27/12/1984 00:00    NULL    27.625  NULL
28/12/1984 00:00    NULL    27.75   NULL
31/12/1984 00:00    12273   28      4.400022371
02/01/1985 00:00    NULL    27.5    NULL
03/01/1985 00:00    NULL    26.75   NULL
04/01/1985 00:00    NULL    25      NULL
07/01/1985 00:00    NULL    24      NULL
08/01/1985 00:00    NULL    25      NULL
09/01/1985 00:00    NULL    25.375  NULL
```

I need the value of c.ATQ to be duplicated over all the following daily dates until it changes next quarter.

Thanks!!

part 2:

```
GVKEY   rankx   rdq                 QTR ATQ         CSH12Q  DATADATE
008068  2   1984-02-03 00:00:00.000 1   11775.402   96.569  1983-12-31 00:00:00.000
008068  3   1984-05-07 00:00:00.000 2   11428.602   96.751  1984-03-31 00:00:00.000
008068  4   1984-08-02 00:00:00.000 3   11642.902   98.104  1984-06-30 00:00:00.000
008068  5   1984-10-18 00:00:00.000 4   11654.5     98.984  1984-09-30 00:00:00.000
```

similarly:

```
DATADATE                ATQ     PRCCD   PATQ    datadate    rdq
1984-01-31 00:00:00.000 NULL    28      NULL    NULL    NULL
1984-02-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    28.625  NULL    NULL    NULL
1984-02-02 00:00:00.000 NULL    27.875  NULL    NULL    NULL
1984-02-03 00:00:00.000 11775.2 26.75   4.55841 1983-12-31  1984-02-03 00:00:00.000
1984-02-06 00:00:00.000 NULL    27      NULL    NULL    NULL
1984-02-07 00:00:00.000 NULL    26.875  NULL    NULL    NULL
1984-02-08 00:00:00.000 NULL    25.75   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Without some more info/sample of source data it's hard to figure out what exactly you need. However, given the question, I assume that using window functions may solve your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't a key already to link the quarterly date, an id could be emulated by using something like

```
 select DATEPART(YYYY,datetimevalue) * 10 + DATEPART(q,datetimevalue)
```

Syntax wise it would look better with a function , but it should work by changing the datetime part of the join to:

```
  DATEPART(YYYY,s1.DATADATE) * 10 + DATEPART(q,s1.DATADATE) = DATEPART(YYYY,c.DATADATE) * 10 + DATEPART(q,c.DATADATE)
```

If that gives double records, a common table expression (with) could be used to get the quarterly data separately first.

Comment: hey, this sort of works but I need to calculate it going forward.. in the example above the value 12273 on 31/12/1984 should only be used on dates after 31/12/1984.. I want to use the current value going forward (using it for the previous dates would create hindsight bias)

Comment: I go it.. adding 1 to the above.. thats it: DATEPART(YYYY,s1.DATADATE) * 10 + DATEPART(q,s1.DATADATE) = DATEPART(YYYY,c.DATADATE) * 10 + DATEPART(q,c.DATADATE) + 1

Comment: Glad you found it. Word of advice however, the + 1 will not work in december with this calulation (it would compare to the fifth season of 2012). However by multiplying by 4 instead of 10 it would be safe to use (10 makes easier readability, but 4 would give a sum of all quarters combined).  Summarized:   DATEPART(YYYY,s1.DATADATE) * 4 + DATEPART(q,s1.DATADATE) = DATEPART(YYYY,c.DATADATE) * 4 + DATEPART(q,c.DATADATE) + 1

Comment: what would you do though, if you had a date that was not stable.. if for example: c.Datadate could be in the fist quarter 01/12/2003 and then in the second quarter be 04/16/2003?

Comment: Do you mean the c datetime should always be of the time of entry? Then I think the safest bet would to store either the entry date or the generated 'quarter id' in the records themselves and join on that date.

Comment: from part 2 edit in the original.. when I do it using datadate it isn't a problem because everything is organized quarterly... but if I need to do it according to RDQ, I can simple break it into dateparts because the days need to match..

Comment: Not entirely sure I got it, but I think you're saying you don't want to match the quarter perse, but rather always use the last available quarterly data per gvkey?

Comment: correct.. the date changes in each quarter.. if the quarter end is 03/01/2012 than the date may be 10 to 20 days after.. I need to use the data available on that date going forward..

Comment: as above, the quarter end 1983-12-31 but the data was only available on 1984-02-03.. thus, I need to use the value 11775.2 on 1984-02-03 going forward until the next quarter

Comment: In the table with the gvkey column, is DATADATE a field in the database or a query result?

Comment: datadate is a field (column) in the table

Comment: the daily price data is updated every day.. while the quarterly data is updated once randomly throughout the quarter.. I want to use the quarterly value divided by the daily value until the next quarter when the quarterly value changes

Comment: For getting the last available entry per item (gvkey), you could use something like shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424465/get-only-last-row-in-each-days-multiple-entries-in-tsql   That would always use the last entry in the quarterly data. As long as you don't have to recreate in history, that would the best bet.