# get only last row in each day's multiple entries

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm stuck trying to sort out the last entry for a day in a query where I get 24 rows for each entity. I've read the quite simlar question with sollution in [this thred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424465/get-only-last-row-in-each-days-multiple-entries-in-tsql), but I'm not able to incorporate it in my existing query.

My existing query:

```
SELECT distinct b.Udc_id as EAN, sax.attrib_01, c.channel_no, a.local_read_time, a.read, a.Status
from register_reads a, lookup_mv_channels1 c, lookup_mv_sdps b
LEFT outer JOIN s_asset@mudr2sebl sa
 ON sa.x_udc_asset_id = b.Udc_id
LEFT outer JOIN s_asset_xm@mudr2sebl sax
 ON sax.par_row_id = sa.row_id
WHERE c.Channel_id = a.channel_id
AND b.meter_id = c.meter_id
AND sax.attrib_02 = 'Y'
AND a.local_read_time >= (SYSDATE) - 1
order by b.Udc_id, a.local_read_time
```

The result from this will for e.g. be:

```
||EAN | ATTRIB_01 | channel_no | LOCAL_READ_TIME   | READ | STATUS||
||1234| ready     |     1      |09/11/2015 01:00:01|     0|  val  ||
||1234| ready     |     1      |09/11/2015 02:00:01|    10|  val  ||
||1234| ready     |     1      |        ...        |   ...|  val  ||
||1234| ready     |     1      |09/11/2015 23:59:01|    60|  val  ||
||3456| ready     |     1      |09/11/2015 01:00:01|   204|  val  ||
||3456| ready     |     1      |        ...        |   ...|  val  ||
||3456| ready     |     1      |09/11/2015 23:58:01|   400|  val  ||
```

The result I want to achieve is:

```
||EAN | ATTRIB_01 | channel_no | LOCAL_READ_TIME   | READ | STATUS||
||1234| ready     |     1      |09/11/2015 23:59:01|    60|  val  ||
||3456| ready     |     1      |09/11/2015 23:58:01|   400|  val  ||
```

Change after feedback from @levelonehuman:

```
SELECT  b.Udc_id as EAN, 
        c.physical_channel_no, 
        a.local_read_time, 
        a.cum_read, 
        a.validation_Status
FROM register_reads a, lookup_mv_channels1 c, lookup_mv_sdps b
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  b.Udc_id, 
                        MAX(a.LOCAL_READ_TIME) AS LOCAL_READ_TIME
               FROM    register_reads, lookup_mv_sdps b
               GROUP BY b.Udc_id) AS t2
    ON b.Udc_id = t2.Udc_id AND b.LOCAL_READ_TIME = t2.LOCAL_READ_TIME
;
```

Comment: Based on a link are you using SQL server ?

Comment: The query doesn't look good. You shouldn't mix comma-separated join syntax they used in the 1980s with up-to-date explicit joins, but only use the latter. You have two outer-joins that don't work, because of criteria in your where clause that renders them mere inner joins. And why do you need distinct? Can the same sax.attrib_01 be found multifold for a register_read and you must eliminate such duplicates?

Comment: Please tag your DBMS.

Comment: Which result do you want precisely: One record per EAN (with the latest local read and just some matching sax, i.e. if there is both attrib_01 'ready' and attrib_01 'done' for one EAN I decide for one)? Or one record per EAN plus sax (e.g. one record for 1234-ready, one for 1234-done, etc.)? Or can't there be different attrib_01s for an EAN? (That would probably mean your datamodel is flawed.)

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** This is for `MSSQL`

You'll need to add in the additional joins for whatever the other tables are, but you can get your last row using `MAX(LOCAL_READ_TIME)` and `GROUP BY EAN`:

```
SELECT  EAN, 
        ATTRIB_01, 
        channel_no, 
        LOCAL_READ_TIME, 
        READ, 
        STATUS
FROM    TableName t1
    INNER JOIN (    SELECT  EAN, 
                            MAX(LOCAL_READ_TIME) AS LOCAL_READ_TIME
                    FROM    TableName
                    GROUP BY EAN
    ) AS t2 ON t1.EAN = t2.EAN AND t1.LOCAL_READ_TIME = t2.LOCAL_READ_TIME
```

The `INNER JOIN` portion will select rows on `TableName` that have the `EAN` and the `MAX(LOCAL_READ_TIME)` - then, you'll join back to `TableName` (the same table) to select the rest of your data based on the `JOIN` criteria.

Effectively, this filters out rows that don't meet the `EAN + MAX(LOCAL_READ_TIME)` criteria.

Comment: What if two records have the same `LOCAL_READ_TIME`?  (it looks like the data has a 1 minute resolution)

Comment: @ebyrob The outer `SELECT` statement will return all rows that meet the criteria of the `INNER JOIN`, so in this case you would see both rows. If the table has an `identity` column, the point is moot. If not, the data will need to be grouped/filtered by some other factor. It's hard to say with what's been given here.

Comment: Tanks for your answeres Thorsten. I will try to write the joins in a better manner. I need to use "Distinct" to aviod multiple indentical rows, due to the sax.attrib_01, as pointed out.

Comment: @levelonehuman, thanks for the sugested solution and the explenations. I see you use "TableName" both in the "From" expression in addition to in the "From" whitin the Inner Join. Do you mean the same table here? In additon I need to incorperate severel tables in the Inner Join since the EAN and the LOCAL_READ_TIME origins from different tables. Try to use your syntax like this, but get feedback that I'm missing key-word. Please find the edit in the post/question above

Comment: @JanBergan yes, this particular `JOIN` joins back to the same table - specifically, whichever table holds the `LOCAL_READ_TIME` value. The idea is to select out the `MAX(LOCAL_READ_TIME)` by `EAN` on that table. From your updated query it looks like you are missing the `a` declaration on `register_reads` in the inner select.